# Не установлен src у <img - страница обновляется несколько раз

Tags: php, html, sql

В общем суть такова:

через PHP я вывожу из базы запись, сортируя их по кол-ву просмотров "ASC"

```
SELECT src, name FROM `image` ORDER BY `shows` ASC LIMIT 1
```

И здесь-же я, добавляю этой записи 1 просмотр

```
UPDATE `image` SET `shows` = shows + 1 WHERE `id` = :id;
```

Все чудесно, выводит 1 запись и добавляет ей же 1 просмотр.

Но проблема вот в чем, если у меня в разметке есть тэг img с неправильным аттрибутом src, у меня срабатывает запрос на добавление просмотра 2 раза, и добавляет не  1 а 2.

Почему так срабатывает - не понимаю.

Вот так если в разметке - добавляет 1 просмотр

```
<img src="<?php echo $result['src']; ?>" alt="">
```

А если вот так стоит, добавляет 2 просмотра

```
<img src="<?php echo $result['src']; ?>" alt="">
<img src="fsdfsd" alt="">
```

Как это работает?

Comment: Какой путь скрипта до файла демонстрации изображения и какой путь подставляется в атрибут src - не совпадают ли они? Если совпадают, то браузер пытаясь получить изображения, еще раз дергает ваш скрипт и UPDATE срабатывает два раза.

Comment: Возможно у Вас все запросы проходят через index.php а там как то не перенаправляет на 404 а настроено повторный запрос если юрл не найдено

Comment: Возможно при 404 реологает, но все равно как то не ясно...

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в браузере на `http://yoursite.com/fsdfsd` и пообновляйте страницу - тоже будут начисляться дополнительные просмотры. Потому что показывается страница `404 Not Found`, которая тоже страница, которая отображает просмотры.

Лучше не показывать картинки, если их нет:

```
<img src="<?php echo sanitize($result['src']); ?>" alt="">
```

А в функции `sanitize` удаляйте недопустимые символы и проверяйте наличие файла ([file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists) или [is_file](http://php.net/is_file)). Потому что иначе кто-то может добавить картинку `test.jpg"><script>alert('Я взломал ваш сайт');</script><img`.

Детальнее об атаке XSS - на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).

Если файла нет, то возвращайте ссылку на заглушечную картинку или выводите инлайновый прозрачный пиксель:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```